Can this extreme, offensive statement be edited out from this question?
What is the story of Vishnu killing sage Bhrighu's wife Kavyamata?

Unfortunately, the Devi Bhagavatam is widely regarded as not being an authentic Hindu scripture;

What does "widely regarded" mean?
It is an important text for Shaktism.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaktism

Devi Gita
The seventh book of the Srimad Devi-Bhagavatam presents the theology of Shaktism.[40] This book is called Devi Gita, or the "Song of the Goddess".[40][41] The goddess explains she is the Brahman that created the world, asserting the Advaita premise that spiritual liberation occurs when one fully comprehends the identity of one's soul and the Brahman.[40][42] This knowledge, asserts the goddess, comes from detaching self from the world and meditating on one's own soul.[40][43]


This has been done and I thank the moderators for it.
